# Wireshark lua Dissector sharing common variable among all packets

Tags: wireshark

I just started with lua plugins in wireshark. I wanted to know if it is possible to create like a global object that can be called by dissector in one packet and used by dissector called by another packet.

Comment: @ HighNESS this looks like script configuration for an application. app config q's should be on superuser site

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly lua has globals which are accessible from different dissectors of a different packet.

Following is a trivial dissector based on that in https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors, with the addition of a variable counter, which is local to the file and global to the dissector:

```
-- test with tshark -r CAP1 -n -X lua_script:filename.lua -V

local counter = 0;

triviala_proto = Proto("triviala", "Trivial Protocol A")
function triviala_proto.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
    pinfo.cols.protocol = "TRIVIALA"
    local subtree = tree:add(triviala_proto, buffer(), "Trivial")
    subtree:add(buffer(0, 2), "++" .. counter .. "/" .. buffer(0, 2):uint())
    counter = counter + 1;
end
udp_table = DissectorTable.get("udp.port")
udp_table:add(7777, triviala_proto)
```

The global is available to other dissectors in the same file (easily tested: just make a matching "trivialb_proto" on port 8888).